# Flutter navbar in page

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I added a navbar in the middle of a modal bottom sheet. And I want it to display different things when you click on them such as location or other details. Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

https://gyazo.com/6b81b3b89ec19a0410bb5345dc2b511c

And this is the tutorial I am following:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

In my code I could add just this part of code:

```
  BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
elevation: 0,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Details',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.business),
        label: 'Describtion',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.school),
        label: 'Location',
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
```

I can not add set state and stuff because it gives me an error for the whole class. What should I add so that I can change the text there you see under the navbar?

Comment: What is the error that you faced?

Comment: Your page must be a stateful widget to use setState().

Comment: the thing is that the page is as a class

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d4946136de98c31508fe86647c4c259a

Comment: You can type your code of the page/class. The screenshot is not proper.

Comment: That EvendWidget also extends from Stateless Widget. Convert it to a stateful Widget by tapping on it easily.

Comment: i posted the code here http://dontpad.com/codeflutter123 sorrt it is that long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224640/discussion-between-akif-and-andrei-marin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your class from a StateFul Widget. After that you can easily change your selected index with a setState() method. It will look like this:

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class EvendWidget extends StatefulWidget { // Here we changed!
  String image;
  String title;
  String location;
  String date;
  String duration;
  String genre;
  String price;

  EvendWidget(
    _image,
    _title,
    _location,
    _date,
    _duration,
    _genre,
    _price,
  ) {
    image = _image;
    title = _title;
    location = _location;
    date = _date;
    genre = _genre;
    price = _price;
    duration = _duration;
  }

  @override
  _EvendWidgetState createState() => _EvendWidgetState();
}

class _EvendWidgetState extends State<EvendWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {},
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        child: Image.asset(widget.image,
                            height: 180.0,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      )),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                    child: Text(widget.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 28,
                            color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Text(widget.location,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Colors.grey))),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                    child: Text(widget.date,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 10),
                    child: Text("Duration: " + widget.duration,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.grey)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 10),
                              child: Text('Genre: ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.black))),
                          Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text(widget.genre,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.white)))
                        ],
                      )),
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      child: Divider(color: Colors.grey)),
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5, left: 20, bottom: 15),
                            child: Text(widget.price + ' RON',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 23,
                                    color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 15),
                            child: Text('for 1 ticket',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    color: Colors.grey)),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 40, bottom: 15, top: 5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0, left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text("Buy",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      color: Colors.white))),
                          new GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                                  context: context,
                                  isScrollControlled: true,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  builder: (context) => Container(
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        0.80,
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                          colors: [
                                            Colors.deepPurple,
                                            Colors.deepPurple
                                          ]),
                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                                        topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                            child: ClipRRect(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                              child: Image.asset(widget.image,
                                                  height: 180.0,
                                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                          .size
                                                          .width *
                                                      0.95,
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                            )),
                                        BottomNavigationBar(
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                                          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                                          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          items: const <
                                              BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                                            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.info_outlined),
                                              label: 'Details',
                                            ),
                                            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.deion_outlined),
                                              label: 'Deion',
                                            ),
                                            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                  Icons.location_on_outlined),
                                              label: 'Location',
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                                          onTap: _onItemTapped,
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  top: 10, left: 30),
                                              child: Text(widget.title,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 28,
                                                      color: Colors.white)),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 30),
                                                child: Text(widget.location,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                        fontSize: 16,
                                                        color: Colors.grey))),
                                            Container(
                                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  top: 10, left: 30),
                                              child: Text(widget.date,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      color: Colors.white)),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  top: 0, left: 30),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Duration: " +
                                                      widget.duration,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      color: Colors.grey)),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width *
                                                    0.95,
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 10, left: 0),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Container(
                                                        margin: const EdgeInsets
                                                                .only(
                                                            top: 0,
                                                            left: 30,
                                                            right: 5),
                                                        child: Text('Genre: ',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .white))),
                                                    Container(
                                                        decoration:
                                                            BoxDecoration(
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              BorderRadius
                                                                  .circular(10),
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                        ),
                                                        padding:
                                                            EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                top: 5.0,
                                                                left: 20,
                                                                right: 20,
                                                                bottom: 5),
                                                        child: Text(
                                                            widget.genre,
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .deepPurple)))
                                                  ],
                                                )),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            margin:
                                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150),
                                            child: RotatedBox(
                                                quarterTurns: 1,
                                                child: IconButton(
                                                  iconSize: 40,
                                                  icon: Icon(Icons
                                                      .arrow_forward_ios_sharp),
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  onPressed: () =>
                                                      Navigator.pop(context),
                                                )))
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 20, bottom: 15, top: 5),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text("View",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Colors.blue)),
                                      Text("More",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Colors.blue))
                                    ],
                                  )))
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }

  // Then we can use it!
  void _onItemTapped(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = value; 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it works! but after, how do i add the list so it can change accordint to the indexes because if i add it under the navbar i get an error like this: https://gyazo.com/1cf3df36c98743fbd0bf69ad8e4fd421

Comment: the thing is that when you click on them, all the text under the banner should change into something else

Comment: I also tried adding a simple list but it is still not working

Comment: Update: i managed to do it but it is not refteshing automatically, i press it i go out go back and than it shows it. what should i do so it can be displayed dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use the bottom bar like in the documentation you should make your screen widget stateful. Read the code in the documentation and you'll see that the scaffold is built inside a stateful widget's state class.